# Can I sell my stocks for less by transferring them to another brokerage?

Tags: stocks, fees, broker, transfer

I would like to sell approximately $35000 in stocks currently held at Edward Jones.  My total portfolio is approx. 1.5 million.  Edward Jones will charge me 1% of the sale.  Would it make sense to transfer those stocks to another company and then sell them at $10 per trade?

Comment: Have you determined whether you would be charged for the transfer and if so, how much?

Comment: I read this title as, "Can I sell my *stocks for less*" rather than, "Can I *sell* my stocks for *less*"

Answer (score 8):

TLDR:  Yes you can.

That is quite a steep price to pay for a trade.  I've used TradeKing previously, which would charge you $5 for that same trade.  Some other brokers are more or less expensive, and it is normally representative of the service one receives.  One option would be Scottrade.  While they are much more expensive than TradeKing, they offer a much higher level of service.  Even at $17 a trade, you'll save a lot of money over the Edward Jones trade.

A big question here is who does your investing now?  Most people are pretty horrible at managing their own investments.  Some professional advice is probably in order.  For most they discover this when their investments are small, mitigating any mistakes made.  You don't have that luxury.  I would highly recommend making sure you have people that can help you make good decisions.

The more I think about it the more I like the move to Scottrade (no affiliation) or one like that (Charles Schwab is another option).  With Scottrade you can go into a local branch and talk things over.  I think they offer some professional management as well.  Schwab will offer the latter but not the former.  However you can call them up and talk on the phone.  Another option is to go with Fidelity and have them manage at least part of your money.  Of course you can always just do a professional, independent money manager.

Another option is to renegotiate with Edward Jones.  Something like:  "Sorry but this is ridiculous, you need to do much better or I am moving all my money."  Its much cheaper to charge you $100 for that same trade than lose the whole account.

Comment: I was looking fees a little while ago and I believe Vanguard will do trades at $0 if you hold $1 million with them.

Comment: While good to point out, with a 1.5m portfolio the difference between a $100 commission and $0 is not material.  Its more important to protect the assets while also seeking some growth in my opinion.

Comment: Agreed but I'm assuming the OP wants to make more trades in the future.  Before moving, a number of options should be considered.

Comment: Your answer was great, but I'm confused by the comment. If I have a $1.5M portfolio, and retire, taking out $60K/yr, $600 is a high price to pay each year. (I assume the withdrawal requires a sale of stock) This is in addition to whatever trades are happening that year.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I think the point was that if you can get them to drop the price for the sale to $100 it's not going to matter much.  I agree if you are talking about a one time transaction but over time this can eat into your returns.  Not so much when you pull the money out to spend it but more during the growth phase.

Comment: The way I figured it is assuming 20 trades per year at 100 per trade.  That is a total of 2K.  That is about .13% of the stock portfolio, which I would classify as not material.

Comment: @JimmyJames - OP has $1.5M with this broker. I'll agree, if he's a buy and holder, the occasional transaction shouldn't keep him up at night. But, even a long term investor might have 10-15% turnover. That can be $2000 in trading fees eating into his profit.

Comment: @PeteB. -  funny we both commented, seconds apart, and both picked $2000 as the example. I respect your opinion, but will also squeeze out costs that provide no value. $2000 can be better spent frivolously, extra dinners out or tickets to Hamilton....

Comment: :^) @JoeTaxpayer.  I think we can both agree that 2K is a small price to pay if it prevents day trading away a significant portion of the portfolio.  However, if that is not an issue paying 0 is a much better choice.